# Removing border around image in ie

Tags: css, internet-explorer

I tried many of the solution on the internet. nothing works.

```
        <a target="_blank" href="" style="outline : none; text-decoration:none;"><img style="border:none;outline : none;"  alt="" src="/Banners/imve.jpg"  /></a>
```

I tried also setting the border color to white in both elements. setting the border size to 0px.. But nothing works why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the following:

```
<a target="_blank" href="" style="outline : 0; border: 0; text-decoration:none;"><img style="border:0;outline : 0;" border="0"  alt="" src="/Banners/imve.jpg"  /></a>
```

Comment: Yes, it will, please see all the code I wrote, especially at: `<img style="border:0;outline : 0;" border="0"`. Please add the last `border="0"` attribute and it will work.

Answer (score 0):

You have `outline:none;` on your `a` tag. This should be `border:none;`

**CSS**

```
a, a img{
border:none;
}
a img{
display: block;
}
```